# Select count from one table and join another table based off of one id

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now I have this query:

```
SELECT s.*, u.username,
FROM submissions s
JOIN users u ON s.user_id
WHERE s.id = 15
```

Which gives me:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
         id: 15
      title: dsaffdsadfsafds
       slug: dsaffdsadfsafds
description: dfsdfsdfsafadsdfasdfs
    user_id: 15
    created: 2014-01-12 14:21:29
   category: autos-vehicles
       type: request
  thumbnail:
    removed: 0
   keywords: dsaffdsadfsafds
         ip: 127001
   username: blahbster
```

Now I want to add a count to that from another table called `submissions_votes`.

```
SELECT count(id) as "submissionVotes"
FROM submissions_votes
WHERE submission_id = 15
```

I tried to combine them like this:

```
SELECT s.*, u.username, 
  (SELECT count(id)
  FROM submissions_votes
  WHERE submission_id = 15) as "submissionVotes",
FROM submissions s
JOIN users u ON s.user_id
WHERE s.id = 15;
```

But I'm getting an error. Need some help here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT s.*, u.username, COUNT(sv.id) votes FROM submissions s INNER JOIN users u ON 
s.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv ON s.id = sv.submission_id 
WHERE s.id = 15 GROUP BY sv.submission_id
```